# bundle update spikes cpu and does nothing

Tags: ruby, bundler

Pretty much what the title says, I run 'bundle update', my CPU spikes, and nothing happens. I've left it for like two hours. Any ideas on what to do?

I use `bundler` version `1.0.15`.

Here is my `Gemfile` content:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'whiskey_disk'
gem 'rails'
gem 'rake'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'juggernaut'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'postmark-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'airbrake'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'haml'
gem 'barista'
gem 'decent_exposure'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'carrierwave-mongoid', require: 'carrierwave/mongoid'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'devise'
gem 'gravtastic'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'bson_ext', require: 'mongo'
gem 'mongoid'
gem 'mongoid-tree', require: 'mongoid/tree'
gem 'mongoid_auto_inc'
gem 'mongoid_search'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-tumblr'
gem 'inherited_resources'
gem 'jammit'
gem 'clockwork'
gem 'stalker'
gem 'ruby-bitly'
gem 'cloudfiles'
gem 'fog'
gem 'embedly'
gem 'zencoder'
gem 'pry'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'ruby-mp3info', require: 'mp3info'
```

Comment: Try running it with `--verbose` option. Once I had some complicated dependencies in my Gemfile and bundler stuck in an endless loop while resolving them.

Comment: doesn't seem to add anything to the output

Comment: Can you share content of you `Gemfile` and bundler version?

Comment: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/527638/

Comment: Well, `verbose` doesn't help, but `DEBUG_RESOLVER=1 bundle install` shows that for some reason bundle goes crazy while resolving your dependencies. Though, after a couple of trials I got that [`Gemfile.lock`](https://gist.github.com/1538932). You can use it or try to specify version for some of the gems (that might help bundler). Anyway, it'd be nice if someone could explain what causes these troubles with bundler.

Answer (score 1):

Bundler is rarely having hard time to resolve the dependencies, therefore the only workaround now is to provide it some "hints" of specifying versions for some dependencies, so it can calculate the rest quickly.

Specify versions for some gems and calculation should be much faster. Good candidate here is Rails.

More info here: https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/1450